# Spring webclient is not logging error response and performing consumer action on receiving error

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I have a spring boot service where APIs are exposed via RouterFunction. Once the API request is received , certain validations are triggered. One of the validation, call another API via webclient to validate if received value exist or not. If value do not exist , it has to log the error message and add the error message in array list.

However, below implementation is neither logging the error nor success message nor able to add the error message in array list.

I also tried to use block() but that gives

```
'IllegalStateException: block()/blockFirst()/blockLast() are blocking, which is not supported in thread reactor-http-epoll-3'
```

If I directly expose one API via RouterFunction just to call that lookup API, everything is working. This shows that making call via validation layer is causing issue, perhaps some issue with synchronous and reactive way of making call.

I am unable to understand the issue with my implementation.Please guide what I am doing wrong.

**Validation Class which is triggering external validation**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class EmployeeValidation{
    
    private final IdentityApiClient identityApiClient;
    
    public List<ErrorDetail> validate(Optional<EmployeeRequestDto> employeeRequest) {
        var errors = new ArrayList<ErrorDetail>();
        employeeRequest
                .ifPresent(employee -> {
                    //some other validations
                    if (errors.isEmpty()) {
                        validateIfIdentityExist(employee.getSecuredEmployeeDetail(), errors::add);
                    }
                });
        return errors;
    }
    
    private void validateIfIdentityExist(SecuredEmployeeDetailDto securedEmployeeDetailDto, Consumer<ErrorDetail> errorDetailConsumer) {
        Optional.ofNullable(securedEmployeeDetailDto)
                .map(SecuredEmployeeDetailDto::getIdentity)
                .ifPresent(identityLocal -> {
                    log.info("Going to retrieve identity [{}] detail", identityLocal);
                    identityApiClient.retrieveIdentityDetail(identityLocal)
                            .doOnError(e -> errorDetailConsumer.accept(new ErrorDetail(REQUEST_INVALID_PARAM, e.getMessage())));

                });
    }
}
```

**Webclient which is calling another API to validate value**

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class IdentityApiClient {

    private final WebClient identityWebClient;
    private final IdentityProperties identityProperties;
    
    public Mono<IdentityDetail> retrieveIdentityDetail(String identity) {
        log.info("Going to retrieve identity [{}] detail", identity);
        return identityWebClient
                .get()
                .uri(identityProperties.getLookupPath(), Map.of("identity", identity))
                .retrieve()
                .onStatus(httpStatus -> httpStatus.equals(UNAUTHORIZED),
                        clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(String.class)
                                .flatMap(identityLookUpErrorResponse -> Mono.error(new IdentityLookUpException(UNAUTHORIZED.value(), IdentityLookUpErrorResponse.builder()
                                        .error(identityLookUpErrorResponse)
                                        .message("Unauthorized Access")
                                        .status(UNAUTHORIZED.value())
                                        .build()))))
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is4xxClientError,
                        clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(IdentityLookUpErrorResponse.class)
                                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(IdentityLookUpErrorResponse.builder()
                                        .error("Received Empty Response Body")
                                        .message("Unknown Identity")
                                        .status(NOT_FOUND.value())
                                        .build()))
                                .flatMap(identityLookUpErrorResponse -> Mono.error(new IdentityLookUpException(identityLookUpErrorResponse.getStatus(), identityLookUpErrorResponse))))
                .onStatus(HttpStatus::is5xxServerError,
                        clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(IdentityLookUpErrorResponse.class)
                                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(IdentityLookUpErrorResponse.builder()
                                        .error("Received Empty Response Body")
                                        .message(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.getReasonPhrase())
                                        .status(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value())
                                        .build()))
                                .flatMap(identityLookUpErrorResponse -> Mono.error(new IdentityLookUpException(identityLookUpErrorResponse.getStatus(), identityLookUpErrorResponse))))
                .bodyToMono(IdentityDetail.class)
                .doOnNext(response -> log.info("Identity [{}] response received", response)) // not getting logged when called via validator class
                .doOnError(e -> log.error("Identity [{}] error response received", identity, e));// not getting logged when called via validator class
    }   
}
```

Comment: Using your favorite IDE, attempt to go deep into the debug mode to understand precisely what is happening line by line. Also, you built a high-coupled code between EmployeeValidation and IdentityApiClient class. Check it out and re-design it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

The method `identityApiClient.retrieveIdentityDetail` returns a `Mono` which is not being subscribed to by anyone. This code in isolation does not do anything.

```java
identityApiClient.retrieveIdentityDetail(identityLocal)
                            .doOnError(e -> errorDetailConsumer.accept(new ErrorDetail(REQUEST_INVALID_PARAM, e.getMessage())));
```

The mantra for reactive programming is

> "Nothing happens until you subscribe"

For the majority of use cases, the underlying framework (in this case spring) will subscribe to the `Mono` for you, as long as you return it from your `RouterFunction`.

I am not fully familiar with your requirement but one possible solution would be to refactor your validator to make it reactive and add it into your reactive stream.

Comment: Validator is pre-existing. I just need to add another validation of identity using webclient. So without interfering with validator code , i need to achieve this extra validation.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The class `EmployeeValidation` needs to be fixed. If you can't interfere with this code, then you can not get the code to work

Comment: What I meant to say is that yes we can change EmployeeValidation to add this extra IdentityValidator but cannot refactor whole EmployeeValidation class as certain other validations are also included.

Comment: @Michal McFadyen subscribe() did the partial job , now I am able to see logs and responses. However, since subscribe() is async , request is going forward to create employee and later we are receiving validation error message. Any suggestion how to stop this and make is synchronous.

Comment: the suggestion on how to solve this is in the answer above. Return the `Mono` from your method and let the underlying framework subscribe to it.